# Excel Marco to average every n rows until end

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macros! Here is an example of my data:

```
Delivery Date   Delivery Hour   Delivery Interval   Settlement Point Name   Settlement Point Price  
01/01/2013  1   1   LZ_WEST 21.71   21.67
01/01/2013  1   2   LZ_WEST 21.64   
01/01/2013  1   3   LZ_WEST 21.80   
01/01/2013  1   4   LZ_WEST 21.51   
01/01/2013  2   1   LZ_WEST 21.26   21.22
01/01/2013  2   2   LZ_WEST 21.20   
01/01/2013  2   3   LZ_WEST 21.35   
01/01/2013  2   4   LZ_WEST 21.08   
01/01/2013  3   1   LZ_WEST 21.01   20.80
01/01/2013  3   2   LZ_WEST 20.65   
01/01/2013  3   3   LZ_WEST 20.86   
01/01/2013  3   4   LZ_WEST 20.66
```

I need a macro to average the settlement prices in col E for intervals 1-4 in col B for each delivery hour and repeat till the end of the data. I would then like to collapse the four intervals into one avg price for the delivery hour. This data came from filtering a larger dataset and I will have a sheet for each month in a year. Is there a straightforward way to macro this repetitive task? Thanks for any assistance offered.

Comment: Please excuse the jumble of data. How can I post my Excel data?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to create a solution? If so, what issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula, make the average formula in E6 look like:

```
=average(D3:D6)
```

Then highlight E3:E6 and drag down.

I made the assumption column D is the one you are averaging, update the formula if not.